# How to draw graph of mathematic function in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to draw graph of function, example y = sin(x) and y = cos(x). How to draw it with out drawing each point (x, sin(x))?
Have any class/method in Cocoa can do this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in feature to plot function output in Cocoa. The [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) library is the leading numerical plotting toolkit, but it provides only data-driven, not function-driven plots. Rasterizing (converting a function to a discrete plot) is a non-trivial problem. As others have pointed out, you want to look into some form of interpolation and do some research on schemes for deciding *which* points to plot so that the output looks "correct" to a human observer. Again, not a trivial task. I believe  [Numerical Recipes](http://www.nr.com/) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [cubic or quadratic Bezier curves](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_Graphics_Drawing_Tutorial_using_Quartz_2D#Drawing_a_Cubic_B.C3.A9zier_Curve) to interpolate your discrete points. Bezier curves are well supported by Quartz2D.

This article goes more into the [math of interpolation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/BezierSpline.aspx), it is not OS X not iOS centric, but the math is just cross platform.